# Instantiating a Flask object within a large application

Tags: python, flask

Suppose I create a Flask server that has a method called foo(). Now also suppose that I have another Python app that wants to create an instance of that server and use foo().

```
my_server = FlaskObject()
my_server.foo()
```

I basically want to have an instance of a Flask server that I can manipulate without having to send http requests.

I feel like there is a simple solution that I'm overlooking but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just do `from app import foo` or something just to grab that `foo` method?

Comment: What is `FlaskObject`?

Comment: @cricketYes, that would work if I just wanted to use the foo() method. However, I want to be able to create(and keep) an instance of a Flask server where I can choose to run the server and use methods that may affect the state of said server from my outer application.

Comment: @dirn It's a hypothetical object that I created to illustrate my problem. I want to be able to hold a reference to a flask server.